# How to check signal drive strength?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

How do we check the signal drive strength on wire? Is it possible?
Normally, we can only check the logical value of a wire either `1` or `0` using conditional check `==` or triple equals `===`.
But it doesn't tell us the strength, e.g. `pull`, `strong` or `weak` etc.

So is there a way to check drive strength? For example, it would be used something like this:

```
wire a;
//... your a assignment
initial begin
//...
if (a && is_weak1(a)) $display("a is weak 1");
end
```

Comment: If the signal shows only 1 or 0, that could show upto two status.

Comment: yes, but that is logical value. What I want is its strength. Logic 1 can be weak1, or strong1 - I want to check this signal strength in my code during the runtime.

Comment: I don't know the definition of pull, strong or weak. If you can determine them from the signal, signal should have multiple values, like voltage in analog fashion.  If signal is smaller than 1.0 volt  that is weak, if signal is larger than 4.0 volts, that is strong, etc.   What is your signal? Is tha value is analog or digital? You should specify more detail about your system.

Comment: @Fumu7 Drive strength does not involve voltage it, in a digital system all voltage should be equal, it is regarding resistance, for example tristate buses with multiple drives are often created with weak pull-downs. Any driver can drive a 1 but no-one drives for a 0. if the bus value is not what you tried to drive then there is bus contention and the drivers back off ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drive strength is shown using the special `%v` character.

```
$display("a is %v" a);
```

The values shown by `%v`

```
Strength   Value   %v
supply     7       Su
strong     6       St
pull       5       Pu
large      4       La
weak       3       We 
medium     2       Me
small      1       Sm
highz      0       HiZ
```

[Source](http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00047.htm).

To check a value for conditional statement in SystemVerilog:

```
string str; 
initial begin
  //...
  str = $sformatf("%v", my_net);
  if (a && (str == "We1")) $display("a is weak 1");
```

NB: because the value 1 is encoded in the string the check that a is high is redundant and could just be:

```
str = $sformatf("%v", my_net);
if (str == "We1") $display("a is weak 1");
```

As [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1959732/greg) pointed out the `$psprintf` is not actually part of the system verilog standard we should use `$sformatf` instead. [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) Section 21.3.3 *Formatting data to a string*.

Comment: It is only for $display. How about checking it inside conditional `if` statement? Pseudocode: if (a == weak1)

Comment: @AldoT As Morgan showed you, you use the string returned by `$psprintf` for your compare. `$psprintf` returns a string with what would be printed to the console by a call to `$display` with the same parameters.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing you don't really need the `if(a &&` in the conditions, since the fact that `a` is `1` is already coded in the `"We1"` code.

Comment: @Tudor, thought about removing the `(a &&` but decided to leave, just to match to the original question. It could be wrapped up in a function which removed the trailing 0/1.

Comment: `$psprintf` is is not part of the language standard though most simulators support it. The equivalent is `$sformatf` [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) section 21.3.3 _Formatting data to a string_